# How to rename a document with bash?

Tags: bash, rename, hosts

I need to make this bash script:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "Checking if root…."
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Not running as root"
    exit
fi
echo -ne "Downloading NEW hosts blocking file: "
wget -qO /tmp/hosts.txt http://deathsrepo.webege.com/hosts.txt
echo "DONE!"
mv /tmp/hosts.text -b etc/
wget -qO /tmp/hosts.bak http://deathsrepo.webege.com/hosts.bak
mv /tmp/hosts.bak -b etc/
rename .txt . *.text
```

To be able to rename hosts.text to hosts. Also when this package is removed I need hosts.bak named to hosts.

Comment: what "package" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file, simply move it:

```
mv hosts.text /etc/hosts
```

If your destination is a directory, your file is moved into it, name unchanged:

```
mv hosts.text /etc/  # file is moved to /etc/hosts.text
```

If the destination is a file, and the destination file exists, the source is moved to the specified destination file, and the file at that destination is overwritten:

```
mv hosts.text /etc/hosts   # file is moved and renamed to /etc/hosts
```

If the destination does not exist, and lacks a trailing slash, your file will be renamed to the destination:

```
mv hosts.text foobar.txt  # file is renamed to foobar.txt
```

Comment: I can't just do that this is being done on iPhones,iPods, and iPads I need to rename hosts.text to hosts and I'm going to have the script remove to original hosts text document before renaming the hosts.text

Comment: @user1996894: You need to outline the limits of your environment in your question then. As your question stands, my answer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Remove the original **hosts:**

```
rm /etc/hosts
```

2 - Rename **hosts.text:**

```
mv /tmp/hosts.text /tmp/hosts
```

3 - Move **hosts.text** to **/etc:**

```
mv /tmp/hosts.text /etc
```

You can move *and* rename at the same time with **mv**. I'll also recommend making a backup instead of removing the original hosts:

```
mv /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak   # Make a backup
mv /tmp/hosts.text /etc/hosts  # Move and rename
```

I didn't really get what you're trying to do, but I think your full script will become something like this:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "Checking if root…."
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Not running as root"
    exit
fi
echo -ne "Downloading NEW hosts blocking file: "
wget -qO /tmp/hosts.txt http://deathsrepo.webege.com/hosts.txt
echo "DONE!"
mv /tmp/hosts.txt /etc/hosts  # replace original hosts with downloaded hosts.txt
wget -qO /tmp/hosts.bak http://deathsrepo.webege.com/hosts.bak
mv /tmp/hosts.bak /etc        # move downloaded hosts.bak to /etc
```